proof of Görtz Wedhorn Theorem 3.42 (closed immersion confusion)
I have a question regarding the statement that there is a bijection between the set of
ideals of $A$ and the set of closed subschemes of $X$ (where $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is an affine scheme). The proofs I am looking at are the ones in Görtz & Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry 1, Theorem 3.42 (page 84) and Theorem II.5.3 in Mumford's Red Book of Varieties and Schemes. I am sorry in advance if this question is basic, but this is my first course in algebraic geometry (so I am a beginner) and the proof of the statement was not complete in the lecture. I could not find any question related to this.
I will use the notation in the book by Görtz & Wedhorn in the following.
I understand the general idea behind the proof. We first reduce to the case that $\varphi = \Gamma(i^\#)$, where $i$ is the closed immersion, is injective.
In the next step, we want to show that the underlying continuous map $i: Z \to X$ is a homeomorphism. It is injective and closed, so we only need to show the surjectivity. Now the proof goes as follows:
Let $s \in A$ with $Z \subset V(s)$. We claim that for $N$ sufficiently large, $\varphi(s^N) = 0$. If $U \subset Z$ is open, such that $(U, \mathcal{O}_{Z|U})$ is affine, we get $U \subset V_U(\varphi(s)|_U)$, hence $\varphi(s)_{|U} \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_z)$ is nilpotent.
I just do not understand, why $U \subset V_U(\varphi(s)|_U)$?
We have $U \subset Z \subset V(s) \subset X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. So any prime ideal in A, that is contained in U, contains $s$. I obviously have to forget a crucial detail, but I do not know how the map $ \varphi$ acts on $s$. Why does it map to an element, that (when restricted to $U$) is contained in all primes that are contained in $U$?
I have the same problem with the proof in Mumfords book. He writes:
Since $i(Z)$ is closed in $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, $i(Z) = V(J)$ for some ideal $J$. If $s \in J, s(x)=0$ for all $x \in V(J)$ (i understand this). But then he concludes that again $\varphi(s) = 0$ at all points of $Z$ (I think this means, that $\varphi(s)(z) = 0$ for all $z \in Z$, which are primes of $A$, since $Z \subset X = \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, but if I am confusing things, it would be nice if someone corrects me). The rest of the proof I understand, but again, I do not see why $\varphi(s)(z) = 0$ for all $z \in Z$. It is the same problem as above.
Again, I am sure it is some easy argument, but it is only the third week of the course, so I am a beginner. I would appreciate a detailed answer. Thanks in advance.

Two tips: 1) if you use $\operatorname{Spec}$ to format $\operatorname{Spec}$, it will display more nicely; 2) the more you can do to help your readers out, the better chance you have of getting an answer. In particular, if you can introduce your notation, that would be great - I (and probably many other potential answerers) do not necessarily have the books you're referring to open (or at our desk, or in our building, or...).

Your summary of the proof from Gortz & Wedhorn is a bit difficult to follow for me (perhaps there is some text missing?), so I'll concentrate on Mumford's proof in the second half of your post.
Suppose $z\in Z$ and $i(Z) \subset V(s) \subset \operatorname{Spec} A$. Then $s$ is in the prime ideal of $A$ corresponding to the point $i(z)$, so localizing we have $s_{i(z)}$ is in the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A,i(z)}$. Since we have a local map of local rings $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A,i(z)} \to \mathcal{O}_{Z,z}$ coming from the morphism $i:Z\to\operatorname{Spec} A$, we have that $\varphi(s)_z$ is in the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{Z,z}$, and therefore $\varphi(s)$ evaluates to zero in the residue field $\kappa(z)$, or equivalently $\varphi(s)(z)=0$.

Thank you very much @KReiser for the answer and the helpful comment!
I am satisfied with the answer and it also answers the step in th other proof:)
I will introduce the notation in the evening. In the book of Görtz & Wedhorn the proof continues, so indeed there is some text missing after the problematic argument, but this has nothing to do with the argument itself (I understand the part that comes after). I copied the problematic part from the book, but I understand that I should have copied a bit more, so you know the context. Thank you again:)
